# Correct use of the Object List Filter Characteristic of the Object Transfer Service

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a question regarding Section 3.5 Object List Filter Characteristic from [Object Transfer Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/object-transfer-service-1-0/). It says:

> If the Server supports the Object List Filter characteristic, it shall support three instances of this characteristic as described in Section 3.5.1.

What does "three instances" mean here? I see only one Object List Filter characteristic with [UUID 0x2AC7](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-numbers/Assigned%20Number%20Types/Assigned_Numbers.pdf). I must admit that Section 3.5.1 doesn't give me any idea what these Object List Filter characteristic instances are.

Does it mean that one may write `<Filter Value 1><Parameter 1><Filter Value 2><Parameter 2><Filter Value 3> <Parameter 3>` to the Object List Filter characteristic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there should be 3 separate characteristics, all with the same characteristic UUID (they will have separate attribute handles, of course). During characteristic discovery, all three should be reported.